# What formula does MongoDB use to compute text index score?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-indexing

My toy DB contains three files. If I create a text index for the field `s` and query the string `"pop"`, I get these scores from MongoDB:

```
{ "s" : "pop", "score" : 1.1 }
{ "s" : "pop pop jump", "score" : 1.25 }
{ "s" : "pop pop", "score" : 1.5 }
```

Therefore, what formula does MongoDB use to compute the score?

Comment: This link might help: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/146tx4yxyn/text-search-score-formula

Comment: Then how do doc 2 and 3 score differently?

Comment: Wow, I totally forgot I wrote that. I was about to go do the same thing again. Thanks! It's originally from a [thread on the mongodb-user list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/99t5WXmUUAg). Docs 2 and 3 differ because doc 2 has an extra word in it. Why do you want to know about the formula, just curious? Or is something about it not working as expected or as desired?

Comment: Hi wdberkeley, just curious. I found that mongoDB promotes a small match count from a relatively small doc, and penalize a big match count from a larger doc. Therefore, I'd like to know the exact formula

Comment: later my NLP/DB friends told me that for text search I should switch to ElasticSearch, which is more professional and configurable, esp. with the powerful faceting... What do you think?

Comment: wdberkeley, I will probably switch to AWS ElasticSearch, which is actually called cloud search... But could you still let me know how each number in the 3 docs are obtained? thanks!